# VMware: Connect to the guest's localhost from the host OS?

Tags: networking, vmware-player

Using VMware Player, is there a way to connect to the guest's localhost from the host?

(In this case, the guest is Ubuntu, the host is Windows 7.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I *think* you're asking is this:

> Can I share some aspect of the guest OS to the host?

*If* that's what you meant, then yes: just setup a samba share on the guest and mount the share on the host (presuming the guest can reach the same network the host is on, *a la* bridged networking).

Comment: Thanks! I was able to set up the samba share, now I'm stuck on the bridged networking.

Comment: lackey - what about the birdged networking has you stuck?

Comment: warren, just have no idea how to set it up (after googling a lot). I've posted a more specific question: http://serverfault.com/questions/100034/bridged-networking-between-win-7-host-ubuntu-8-04-guest-vmware

Comment: lackey - not sure where your question went.. however, the short version is that I don't think Player, *per se*, can alter the VM settings. You'd need to load the VM in Server (free) or Workstation, make the change, then rerun it in Player.

Comment: happy to assist :)

Comment: VMWare Player allows you to choose between NAT & bridged networking, at least in v3.x, which also allows you to create VMs.

Answer (score 0):

How to open the localhost development server in the operating system installed in the VMware subsystem

https://gist.github.com/artemsites/e549ef93e0e87b6b8dae40a8a1b685f3

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/573951)